# Add Archive to distributed cache pigServer in local mode

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am trying to add an archive file to distributed cache in pig, while running it in local mode using pigServer.

DistributedCache.addArchiveToClassPath(new Path(new URI("path to archivefile#symlink")),conf);

this doesnt seem to be working though.

How do i add an archive file and add a symlink to pig , while running it using pigServer in local mode ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the job in local mode the distributed cache is not supported.

It would give you a warning as below if you keenly look into your log.

```
2015-10-05 23:22:56,675 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Distributed cache not supported or needed in local mode.
```